# JS parsing with flash

Tags: javascript, php, actionscript-3, flash

hi i am new on javascript and i have player name `player.swf` i am getting list of videos from the database like `videos/dhoom3.flv` and passing it from there to js and then to flash for that i have use

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function playFirstVid() // plays the first video when the page is loaded
{
sendToJavaScript("videos/dhoom3.flv");
}

function sendToJavaScript( id ) 
{
var  name = getMovieName("player");
alert(id);
getMovieName("player").sendToFlash( id );
}

function getMovieName(movieName) 
{ 
 if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) 
{ 
 return window[movieName];
} 
else 
{ 
 return document[movieName];
} 
} 
</script>
```

Firstly is it right way ? For now its not showing my video in player of flash because it says sendToFlash function is missing so can anyone tell what to do next?

Comment: sendToFlash is method defined in the flash movie so if it is missing or flash not initialized then it will not work.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela how to add it if its not there ?

Comment: this method must be part of the player.swf so if it is not there it means either you have to add code and publish player.swf. You could also calling wrong method (e.g. you;ve copied code from somehere) or simply at the moment the method was called the SWF was not initiated so no code accessible.

Answer (score 0):

As [Lukasz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236147/js-parsing-with-flash#comment-30191077) pointed out, if the function does not exist on the class, you can't call it. Assuming it is a public function, you can call any method on an swf by dot.notation.

```
mySWF.theFunctionName(myArguments);
```

Depending on how you wire your events (and I would recommend a unified event listener), it's just a matter of sending that numerically indexed string to your play method.

**Note:** The following is not using a unified listener, but is in keeping with you example.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var videosArr = ["videos/dhoom3.flv", "videos/dhoom2.flv", "videos/dhoom1.flv"];

function playFirstVid() {
    playVid(videosArr[0]);
}

function playVid(filename) {
    var player;

    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        player = window[movieName];
    } else {
        player = document.getElementById("player");
    }

    try {
        player.sendToFlash(filename);
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}

</script>
```